# Using Retrofit to extract different data from a single key

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

So, I think this is a pretty simple solution and I may just be over thinking it.

I have access to an api and I get the following json structure back:

```
{
  "request": 
  {
    //request stuff
  },
  "errors": 
  [
    //if there are any errors, it will show here
  ],
  "code": 200,
  "response": 
  [
    //this can be an array or an object 
  ]
}
```

So if i ask for a user, the "response" becomes a json object that contains a key "login" and I can get the user data from it. But if i ask for a list of pics, the "reponse" is a json array of picture objects.

How would you suggest I go about creating the POJOs using Retrofit/GSON with this?

The solution that I came up with was to create an abstract ApiResponse class that contains request, errors, code, and response. Response will be a interface that other classes can implement. So for example with the User:

```
public class UserApiResponse extends ApiResponse

    private int code;
    private List<String> errors;
    private UserResponse response;
```

And UserReponse would be like this:

```
public class UserResponse extends Response

    //has all user data
```

Would this work? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better way for ApiResponse using generics. You ApiResponse can look like

```
public class ApiResponse<T extends Response>
    private int code;
    private List<String> errors;
    private T response;
```

Retrofit call will be like this

```
@GET("/example/") ApiResponse<UserResponse> getUsers();
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Retrofit won't have trouble hydrating POJOs with generics?

Comment: @Sree I use generics with Retrofit in my projects without troubles.